# Trocar a toolbar do CKEditor

Tags: php, composer, ckeditor

Estou usando o CKEditor em um site meu em PHP usando o Composer para instalar o CKEditor.  E configurei vários tipos de *toolbar* no arquivo `config.js` dele. Quando eu altero a *toolbar* que eu quero no arquivo `config.js` ele troca no site, mas tem páginas que eu gostaria que fosse uma *toolbar* diferente da que eu escolhi no `config.js`.

Como faço para trocá-la diretamente na página que eu quero?

Answer (score 2):

Use ToolbarSets.

**config.js**

```
config.ToolbarSets = new Object() ;
config.ToolbarSets["MinhaToolbar"] = [
['EditSource','-','Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteWord','-','Find','-','Undo','Redo','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat','-','Link','RemoveLink','-','Table','Rule','SpecialChar'] ,
['Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough','-','Subscript','Superscript','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyFull','-','InsertOrderedList','InsertUnorderedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','ShowTableBorders','ShowDetails'] ,
['FontStyle','-','FontFormat','-','Font','-','FontSize','-','TextColor','BGColor']
] ;
```

**sua-pagina.html**

```
var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor( 'FCKeditor1' ) ;
oFCKeditor.ToolbarSet = 'MinhaToolbar' ;
oFCKeditor.Create() ;
```

Mais detalhes em http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Toolbar .

Answer (score 0):

Eu também precisei um dia trabalhar com um toolbar mais reduzido e outro default,
crie um  class no Javascript dessa maneira:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var EditorHtml = function () {
        var name;
        var editorsmall;
        EditorHtml.prototype.Name = function (value) {
            this.name = value;
        };
        EditorHtml.prototype.EditorSmall = function (value) {
            if (value == true || value == false) {
                this.editorsmall = value;
            } else {
                this.editorsmall = false;
            }
        }
        EditorHtml.prototype.Render = function (value) {
            if (value != undefined) {
                this.name = value;
            }
            if (this.editorsmall == true) {
                var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this.name, {
                    toolbar: 'Custom',
                    toolbar_Custom: [
                        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
                        { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format'] },
                        { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
                        { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Blockquote', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight'] },                    
                        { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
                        { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe'] },
                        { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', '-', 'About'] }
                    ]
                });
            } else {
                var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this.name);
            }
            CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor, '/Content/ckeditor/ckfinder/');
        };
    }
</script>
```

---

Como exemplo um [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) com o nome de ***Texto***

```
<textarea name="Texto" id="Texto"></textarea>
```

---

Chamando a classe dessa forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var editor = new EditorHtml();
   editor.EditorSmall(true);
   editor.Render("Texto");
</script>
```

Todas as configurações que deseja criar um novo **toolbar** está no [docs ckeditor](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Toolbar), aonde está na `class` *EditorHtml* a configuração `toolbar_Custom`, você faças as devidas alterações, tendo então um tipo default e outro configurado com o seu estilo.

*Referências*

- [Toolbar Configuration](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Toolbar)
- [JavaScript Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)
- [HTML `<textarea>` Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)